# How pass a local variable in Json path during data extraction using Json_value function in sql sever select statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, json

My Query is

```
declare @id INT
set @id = 69
select 
   (JSON_VALUE(cast(ad.data_map as varchar(max)),'$.dataMap."69".value')) CorrespondanceNumber,
   (JSON_VALUE(cast(ad.data_map as varchar(max)),'$.dataMap.***"@id"***.value')) Agency,
   (JSON_VALUE(cast(ad.data_map as varchar(max)),'$.dataMap."69".value')) Protocal
from actions_new a
  left join action_data ad on ad.id_ref = a.id
where baid = 12;
```

Comment: I removed that tags for Postgres and Oracle as this is clearly (only) for  SQL Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should cast @id to varchar and concate it. like this.

```
(JSON_VALUE(cast(ad.data_map as varchar(max)),'$.dataMap.***"'+cast(@id as varchar)+'"***.value')) Agency,
```

Complete query is. Hope this will help you.

```
declare @id INT
set @id = 69
select 
(JSON_VALUE(cast(ad.data_map as varchar(max)),'$.dataMap."69".value')) CorrespondanceNumber,
(JSON_VALUE(cast(ad.data_map as varchar(max)),'$.dataMap.***"'+cast(@id as varchar)+'"***.value')) Agency,
(JSON_VALUE(cast(ad.data_map as varchar(max)),'$.dataMap."69".value')) Protocal
from actions_new a
left join action_data ad on ad.id_ref = a.id
where baid = 12;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks its working

Comment: @PrabinSwain Then you should mark this answer correct.

Comment: +cast(@id as varchar)+ not working sql server 2016 error throughout The argument 2 of the "JSON_VALUE or JSON_QUERY" must be a string literal.